# createLookAtLH-Transformation

Tags: php, matrix, 3d, linear-algebra

i am still learning to work with linear algebra and matrices. so pls try to avoid using technical terms as much as possible :D

ive created this "createLookAtLH" function:

```
  function createLookAtLH($cameraPosition, $cameraTarget, $cameraUpVector)
  {
    $zAxis = normalized3(array(
      $cameraPosition[0] - $cameraTarget[0],
      $cameraPosition[1] - $cameraTarget[1],
      $cameraPosition[2] - $cameraTarget[2]
    ));
    $xAxis = cross(normalized3($cameraUpVector), $zAxis);
    $yAxis = cross($zAxis, $xAxis);
    return inverseMatrix(array(
      $xAxis[0], $yAxis[0], $zAxis[0], 0,
      $xAxis[1], $yAxis[1], $zAxis[1], 0,
      $xAxis[2], $yAxis[2], $zAxis[2], 0,
      $cameraPosition[0], $cameraPosition[1], $cameraPosition[2], 1
    ));
  }
```

normalized3, cross and inverseMatrix are working without problems (checked with several tests)

now i am creating the matrix and testing with a little example

```
  $view = createLookAtLH(array(-10,0,0), array(0,0,0), array(0,0,-1));
  $v = array(0, 1, 1, 0);
  $v = doSomething($view, $v);
  print_r($v);
```

the "doSomething" function (dont know how to call this operation) is following:

```
  function doSomething($matrix, $vector)
  {
    return array(
      ($matrix[00] * $vector[0]) + ($matrix[01] * $vector[1]) + ($matrix[02] * $vector[2]) + ($matrix[03] * $vector[3]),
      ($matrix[04] * $vector[0]) + ($matrix[05] * $vector[1]) + ($matrix[06] * $vector[2]) + ($matrix[07] * $vector[3]),
      ($matrix[08] * $vector[0]) + ($matrix[09] * $vector[1]) + ($matrix[10] * $vector[2]) + ($matrix[11] * $vector[3]),
      ($matrix[12] * $vector[0]) + ($matrix[13] * $vector[1]) + ($matrix[14] * $vector[2]) + ($matrix[15] * $vector[3])
    );
  }
```

this is the expected result i am getting: 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => -1 [2] => 0 [3] => 10 )

but now when i try to use

```
$v = array(100, 1, 1, 0);
```

then the result dosnt change. shouldnt it be (1, -1, 100, ...) ?
or do i think wrong about something ?

any answer would make me happy =)

Answer (score 0):

You are working with [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations). A point is typically of the form `(X, Y, Z, 1)` (though there are other uses for the `W` coordinate). The translation due to the cameraPosition should be in the column: `[0][3], [1][3], [2][3]`, which is only applied by setting `W = 1`.